# 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17)

Tags: flutter, gradle, jvm

I´m building a flutter application in Android Studio and keep getting this error after installing a package when trying to build the application.
This is the full error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_image_compress_common:compileDebugKotlin'.
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
  Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

As the error states that the current target is version 1.8, I tried to adjust the android/app/build.gradle file like this:

```
...
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}

android {
    namespace 'de.dthinking.app'
    compileSdkVersion 34

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
  ...
}
```

Executing **./gradlew --version** has this output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-02-13 13:15:21 UTC
Revision:     62ab9b7c7f884426cf79fbedcf07658b2dbe9e97

Kotlin:       1.8.10
Groovy:       3.0.13
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17 (Oracle Corporation 17+35-LTS-2724)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Other solutions adjusted the gradle settings, but they are not displayed in my case:
[android studio overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyAuL.png)

I got it to work by adjusting the android/build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KaptGenerateStubs).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

This does not work when I set the jvmTarget to "17", the same error from the beginning occurs.
But I would like to use version 17 instead of 1.8.
I would really appreciate an explanation as to why my changes to the android/app/build.gradle do effectively nothing. Are there any other files that need to be adjusted?

Comment: I am facing this problem in native Kotlin app not Flutter. I have same issue. I did all as 17 or "17" in all modules. Clean project. Then the error disappeared.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, it does work when setting the version to 1.8 for all packages, but I did not find a way to use version 17.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and the following worked for me:

In `app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }
    ...
}
```

Without adjustments needed in `android/build.gradle`.
Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Could not find method jvmToolchain() for arguments [17] on object of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin

Comment: @Dani you probably set `jvmToolchain(17)` in the `kotlinOptions` block instead of `kotlin`. You need to use`kotlin { jvmToolchain(17) }` and not `kotlinOptions { jvmToolchain(17) }`

Answer (score 0):

After so much research only one option found is:

`flutter_image_compress_common` Only support `7.+ gradle` version
don't use `8.+ gradle` version.

[image: Example]

And you can go with `compileOptions 17`.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Vishal's OP, I ran into this issue with mapbox_maps_flutter plugin after upgrading AGP ~8.1. You may run into something similar if you are upgrading a package in your project that requires Gradle 8 (i.e. flutter_stripe). After ensuring my gradle JDK and JAVA_HOME were pointing to Java 17 the process to fix was:

Open your Flutter android Project in Android Studio. Whichever package is causing the issue, in my case mapbox_maps_flutter look at the build.gradle file for the package, and upgrade the kotlin, kotlinOptions as well as compile options to Java 17, or of course whichever is causing you issues. Thanks a lot! I was stuck here for a few days.